# ¿Cómo borrar un archivo de la tarjeta SD en android 10?

Tags: android, kotlin

Manejar los archivos en android 10, no es algo imposible, he instalado ya varios gestores de archivos de terceros y todos borran, editan, copian mueven etc perfectamente. Intento crear una pequeña aplicación que borre un archivo y para ello he utilizado `java.io.File`

```kotlin
    pathSource = "/storage/sdcard/archivo.txt"
    val source = File(pathSource)
    source.delete()
```

Pero no funciona

> exception: Permission Denied

Utilizando `java.nio.file`

```kotlin
    val path:Path = Paths.get(pathSource)
    Files.delete(path)
```

recibo este error

> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException

He agregado todos los permisos que me fueron posibles, en el manifest, y en tiempo de ejecución.

A tener en cuenta es que el permiso de escritura `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` a pesar de que lo he puesto en tiempo de ejecución no se ve en los permisos de la app una vez ya instalada, sin embargo es lo mismo para los gestores de archivos que he instalado, ellos solo tienen principalmente dos permisos: Almacenamiento y Teléfono, no tengo que concederles más nada, casi todas todas las librerías que he probado o están deprecadas o me dan el mismo error. También puse `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` en el manifest y nada, he probado con versiones anteriores del sdk.

**MainActivity.kt:**

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        checkPermissions()
        deleteFun()
    }

    private fun checkPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION), 333)
    }

    private fun deleteFun(){
        val pathSource = "/storage/sdcard/archivo.txt"
        val source = File(pathSource)

        val path:Path = Paths.get(pathSource)

        Files.delete(path)
        source.delete()
    }
}
```

**El Manifest:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.justatest">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.JustATest">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: No investigaste sobre el scoped storage? Se supone que no debes acceder a los archivos directamente por su ruta a menos que tu app sea un antivirus o un gestor de archivos, en cuyo caso debes pedir el permiso `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.  Si nos das más información seguramente podemos ofrecerte alternativas. Cuál es tu caso de uso real? De dónde sale ese archivo y cómo obtendrías su ruta?

Comment: Hola, lo que realmente quiero hacer es un pequeño gestor de archivos, la ruta la consigo así:  ```kotlin  
 val url = "storage/3C11-8A99/"              val sdCard = File(url)```  y luego con _sdCard.listFiles_ obtengo un array que uso en un reciclerview, el permiso ```MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE```. lo tengo en el manifest y también lo pido en tiempo de ejecución

Comment: tengo el mismo problema, solo que mi aplicación es un reproductor de música, todo funciona bien pero al intentar borrar canciones que se ubican en la tarjeta sd con ruta /storage/A515-1609/.... no manda ningún error .delete siempre devuelve false ¿Encontraste solución a tu problema?

Answer (score 2):

La forma que usas para pedir permisos está obsoleta. Debes reemplazarla por la API [Activity Result](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Para ello debes crear un `ActivityResultLauncher` con el método [registerForActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultCaller#registerforactivityresult) y luego solicitar el permiso con el método `launch()` del launcher, pasándole como argumento un permiso o array de permisos, según el contract elegido (`RequestPermission` o `RequestMultiplePermissions`). Ejemplo:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    ...

    private val launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) {
        if (it) {
            // permiso concedido
            deleteFun()
        } else {
            // permiso rechazado
        }
    }

    private fun requestPermission() = launcher.launch(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
}
```

En el manifest, para versiones anteriores a android 10 sólo necesitas declarar el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Para android 10 también debes agregar el atributo `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage` con el valor `true`.

A partir de android 11, tanto el atributo `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage` como el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` ya no sirven. Sin embargo añadieron un permiso similar llamado `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` que puedes pedir si tu app está dentro de los [casos de uso válidos](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955#zippy=%2Cpermitted-uses-of-the-all-files-access-permission) y no te es suficiente con las [alternativas recomendadas](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#remove-item).

Por ser un permiso especial, las formas normales de pedir permisos no funcionan. Tienes que pedirlo haciendo algo como esto

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    ...

    private val launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
            // permiso concedido
            deleteFun()
        } else {
            // permiso rechazado
        }
    }

    private fun requestPermission() {
        val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION)
        intent.data = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
        launcher.launch(intent)
    }
}
```

Y recuerda que es preferible obtener la ruta de la sdcard a partir de `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` en lugar de hardcodearla como en tu ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo pude hacerlo mediante un Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE
Te dejo el código de como lo implemente solo que esta en java

Primero lanzo el intent desde un alertDialog

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(Reproduciendo.getInstance()).setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF0000'>!!ALERTA¡¡")).setMessage(" ¿Desea eliminar la cancion: " + f.getName() + "?")
                    .setPositiveButton(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF0000'>Si"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                            intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, getFilesDir());
                            startActivityForResult(intent,200);
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF0000'>No"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            Toast.makeText(Reproduciendo.getInstance(), "No se elimino la Cancion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).show();
```

Esto nos muestra el sistema de archivos, tenemos que seleccionar la carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo a borrar. Y en ActivityonResult asigno permisos y elimino desde contentUri

```
@Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == 200 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String treeUri = null;
                if (data != null){
//treeUri es un string 
                    treeUri = data.getDataString();
                }
                Log.d("Regresa", "onActivityResult: "+treeUri);
                if (treeUri != null ) {
//se convierte en uri
                    UriSD= Uri.parse(treeUri);
                    Log.d("ResultFinal: "," --"+treeUri+"--"+UriSD);
                    content=getContentResolver();
//Se asignan los permisos al uri
              content.takePersistableUriPermission(UriSD,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                    try {
                        if (reproducir.get(pos).isPlaying()) {
                            reproducir.get(pos).pause();
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){}
                    if(Elim!=null) {
                        Log.d( "Eliminar: ","Si existe");
                        File provider=new File(Elim);
//Se crea un documentFile con el uri al que le dimos permisos y listamos los archivos
                        DocumentFile doc=DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(getApplicationContext(),UriSD);
                        DocumentFile[] index=doc.listFiles();
                        Uri uri=null;
                        DocumentFile delete=null;
                        for(int a=0;a<index.length;a++){
//Buscamos nuestro archivo a borrar
                            if(provider.getName().equals(index[a].getName())) {
    
                                Log.d("DocumetFile", "Nombre: "+index[a].getName()+":Uri-"+index[a].getUri()+"-Permiso-"+index[a].canWrite());
  //Creamos un documentFail con el uri correspondiente 
                         delete=DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(getApplicationContext(), index[a].getUri());
                            }
                        }
                        myHand.removeCallbacks(CorreAnim);
                        myHand.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                        handlerAnim.removeCallbacks(UpdateSongTime);
                        handlerAnim.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                        reproducir.get(pos).stop();
                        reproducir.get(pos).release();
//y aqui procedemos al delete
                        boolean result=delete.delete();
                        Log.d("Delete", "Eliminar: "+result+"--"+provider);
                            try {
                            if (result){
                                for(int a=0;a<Original.size();a++){
                                    Log.d("eliminar"+Elim, "lista: "+Original.get(a).getUri());
                                    if(Elim.equals(Original.get(a).getUri())){
                                        canciones.remove(a);
                                        reproducir.remove(a);
                                        Original.remove(a);
                                        Log.d("Removido de listas", ": "+videoList.get(a).getUri());
                                        if(Elim.equals(listaADP.get(a).getUri())){
                                            listaADP.remove(a);
                                            Canciones.adaptadorBiblioteca.notifyItemRemoved(a);
                                            Log.d("Notifica", ":a Canciones ");
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
    
                                }
                                preferencias();
                                Next();
                                myHand.postDelayed(CorreAnim, 200);
                                Toast.makeText(Reproduciendo.getInstance(), " La canción:  " + provider.getName() + " Se elimino correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }else{
                                Log.d( "Eliminar: ","result "+result);
                                Next();
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            Log.d( "Result: ","Ex -"+e);
                        }
    
                    } else {
                        Log.d("Eliminar: ", "   no es un archivo valido :  " + Elim);
                        Toast.makeText(Reproduciendo.getInstance(), " No es un archivo valido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        reproducir.get(pos).start();
                        myHand.postDelayed(CorreAnim, 200);
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.d("result ","uri is empty!");
                }
            }
        }
```

con eso deberías poder eliminar archivos de tu SD, no requiere ningún permiso especial.

Saludos.