# Obtener ruta real de video "storage/emulated/.." con uri "content://media/...." de MediaStore

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, android-manifest

Estoy descargando un video con okHttp3 para luego procesarlo con [ffmpeg](https://github.com/SimformSolutionsPvtLtd/SSffmpegVideoOperation), entonces tengo lo siguiente.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var client : OkHttpClient
    private val TAG ="dwts"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        client = OkHttpClient()
        val urlVid = "https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-man-climbing-a-mountain-seen-from-above-34900-large.mp4"
        downloadFile(urlVid,"fileName")

    }

    fun downloadFile(url:String,nm:String){
        val request: Request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {}

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    response.body?.byteStream()?.saveToMusicFolder(applicationContext,nm)
                }

            }

        })
    }


    fun InputStream.saveToMusicFolder(context: Context, fileName: String) {
        val resolver = context.contentResolver
        val uri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

            val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "$fileName.mp4")
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES + "/" + "AppName")
            }

            resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)

        } else {

            File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES),
                "$fileName.mp4").toUri()

        }

        resolver.openOutputStream(uri!!)!!.use { copyTo(it) }
        close()

        Log.i(TAG, uri.toString()) //  content://media/external/video/media/7095

        val sharedIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
            type = "video/mp4"
        }

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharedIntent, fileName))

    }
}
```

Hasta ahí todo funciona bien, el problema es, que para procesar el video con ffmpeg necesito una ruta de archivo de tipo

```
storage/emulated/0/Movies/AppName/fileName.mp4
```

y no la uri que obtuvo con contentResolver

```
content://media/external/video/media/7095
```

he probado con esa pero no funciona.

Estuve investigando mucho, sin embargo debido a las constantes cambios en el tratamiento de archivos respecto a las distintas versiones de android, ha sido confuso encontrar una solución.
Estoy probando esto en Android 11 con

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
 android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
   
    }
```

Entonces como podría obtener `storage/emulated/0/Movies/AppName/fileName.mp4`  o existe alguna otra forma de implementación para lo que deseo realizar

Importante señalar que

```
File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES),
                "$fileName.mp4").toUri()
```

Devuelve `storage/emulated/0/Movies/fileName.mp4` , justo lo que se necesita, sin embargo esto estaría deprecado, y genera open failed: EEXIST (File exists)

**Actualización**
Agregando

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Ya no genera open failed: EEXIST (File exists), pero sigue estando deprecado, el archivo se descarga pero no lo muestra en la galería .

**Notas**
El archivo se descarga correctamente y se encuentra en la carpeta deseada, también se muestra en la galería.
Sin embargo, en la galería, no se sitúa como ultimo elemento añadido, es decir no se encuentra como primer elemento, sino que se esta posicionando de acuerdo a la fecha en que fue creado, supongo que el video tiene como metadato de creación 9 de Nov de 2020, por ejemplo, entonces se puede encontrar en la galería pero al final de esta , organizado en la posición que le corresponde de acuerdo a la fecha que tiene su metadato.
Aclaración por si no encuentra el video en su galería, creare otra pregunta para ello.

Comment: Prueba con algun de las soluciones de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore). O con librerías externas como [PickIt](https://github.com/HBiSoft/PickiT)

Comment: Solamente se pueden usar rutas absolutas con los archivos que están dentro de las carpetas especificas de tu app. Es decir las que obtienes con los métodos `getFilesDir()` y `getCacheDir()` o bien `getExternalFilesDir()` y `getExternalCacheDir()`. Probablemente tu mejor opción sea mover los archivos a una de esas carpetas. Aunque con `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` también debería ser posible. Estás seguro que pediste el permiso correctamente? Revisa esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/480267/198326

Comment: @javdromero me sirvió de mucho las soluciones de la otra pregunta.

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE , ayudo. Tenia que pedir el permiso correctamente como dices.

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolverlo usando el siguiente código encontrado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore) .

```
private fun getPh(uri: Uri): String {
    val selectedImage: Uri = uri
    val filePathColumn = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)

val cursor = contentResolver.query(
    selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null
)
cursor!!.moveToFirst()

val columnIndex = cursor!!.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0])
val filePath = cursor!!.getString(columnIndex)
cursor!!.close()

return filePath
```

}

Pasando un uri como esta

```
content://media/external/video/media/72607260
```

Se puede obtener

```
/storage/emulated/0/Movies/AppName/fileName.mp4
```

Sin embargo es importante señalar que en `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` DATA esta deprecado, realmente no se que significa, es decir se que no se debería usar por que hay una opción nueva que lo remplaza, sin embargo no se que tanto pueda perjudicar el usarlo, lo que me hace pensar que podría ocasionar errores, en algún monento.

Pero es solo una opinión ya que realmente no se si tendrá alguna implicancia al momento de ser usado en las distintas versiones de Android.

Comment: No olvidar pedir los permisos necesarios correctamente.